# Show that if $f(a) = 0$, then $a ^{−1}$ is a zero of the polynomial $g(x) = a_0x ^n + a_1x ^{n−1} + ... + a_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, field-theory, roots

Let $F$ be a field, $f(x) = a_nx^n + ... + a_1x + a_0$ a polynomial in $F[x]$, and let $a$ be a nonzero element
of $F$.

Show that if $f(a) = 0$, then $a^{−1}$ is a zero of the polynomial $g(x) = a_0x^n + a_1x
^{n−1} + ... + a_n$.

My attempt:

We have $a.a^{-1}=1$ and thus $a^{-1} \not= 0$ since $a \not= 0$.

Now, if $f(a) = 0$, then $a_na^n +...+ a_1a + a_0 = 0$ and thus $a_n =...=a_1=a_0=0$ (since $a \not= 0$

$a^{-1}$ is a zero of $g(x)$ if $g(a^{-1})=0$.

Now $g(a^{-1}) = a_0(a^{-1})^n + a_1(a^{-1})^{n-1} +...+ a_n$

How to continue from here, any help please? Thank you.

Comment: multiply through by $a^n$.

Comment: why should all the $a_i$ be 0?

Comment: HInt: expand $\frac{f(a)}{a^n}$ and note that $\frac{a^i}{a^n} = a^{i-n} = (a^{-1})^{n-i}$.

Answer (score 5):

It is *not* true the every $a_k$ must be $0$. For instance, $a=2$ is root of $x-2$, but the coefficientis of $x-2$ are not all equal to $0$.

If $a_na^n+a_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1a+a_0=0$, then$$\frac{a_na^n+a_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1a+a_0}{a^n}=0,$$which is the same thing as asserting that$$a_0\left(a^{-1}\right)^n+a_1\left(a^{-1}\right)^{n-1}+\cdots a_{n-1}a^{-1}+a_n=0.$$